# JavaScript もしくは プログラミング における 数字 と 数値 の違い

Tags: プログラミング言語

**「数字」 と 「数値」 の違い について教えてください。**

JavaScript もしくは 各プログラミング言語 において、上記を表記する場合は、
一般的に、型も含まれていると判断して良いのでしょうか？

> ・数字の1 → string　の '1'
>    ・数値の1 → integer の 1 
>   ・数値文字列の1 → string　の '1'

あるいは、「数字」「数値」は日本語表記の問題なので、型とは無関係？

もしくは、使う人や文脈によって異なる？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

日本語の言葉の意味合い的に分かれていますが、JS上での規定はありません。  
数字と数値は混同されることが多いですね。

数字(Number) = 数を表示するための文字(記号)。つまり文字列です。  
'1'以外にも'一'や'壱'、'Ⅰ'も該当します。

数値(Numeric value) = 数その物の値。例えばparseInt()の結果や(5*3)といった計算結果等の
数を表す概念で表示形式は関係しません。

これだけだと文字列型と数値型に分かれているように見えますが、  
1でも表示の意味で使えば'1'と同じように数字と呼びますし、その逆もありえます。  
こういった使い方によって呼び方が違う部分が混同に拍車をかけていると思います。

問題になりそうであれば前もって定義しておいたほうがいいでしょう。

> デジタル大辞泉の解説
>   すう‐じ【数字】
>   １ 数を表すのに用いる記号や文字。アラビア数字（「1、2」など）・ローマ数字（「Ⅰ、Ⅱ」など）・漢数字（「一、二」など）の類。
>   ２ 統計・成績・計算など、数字によって表される事柄。「―に強い」「―がものを言う」
>   ３ 数個の文字。
>
> すう‐ち【数値】
>   １ 計算や、計量・計測をして得られた数。
>   ２ 文字式の中の文字に当てはまる具体的な数。

Answer (score 2):

`もしくは、使う人や文脈によって異なる？`

概ね。その理解で構いません。

例えば「C言語プログラミングなるほど実験室」のようなテキストブックでは
「数値」「数字(文字コードで表現するもの)」「数字列(文字列のうち数字だけで構成されているもの)」と分けて説明しています。

例えばブラウザのフォーム入力は「数値」と表現されていても。一般的に、サーバー側では、文字列をパースして、それが「数字だろう／数字のはずだ」と処理します。逆に、ブラウザに表示された1桁の数字が「数値」なのか「数字」なのか「1文字だけの数字列」なのか。そんなのユーザーは意識しません。

意識が低いと齟齬も起こしやすくなります。
例えば「数値を入力する」という場合に、-1,234,567.89 という入力は、正しいのか正しくないのか。そういう揉め事がおきたりもします。また上記テキストブックの「数字」も内部的には「数値」でしかありません。

このように、意味自体が通用しても。見る（使う）立場によって、その意味が有用かどうか、意識するかどうかが別なのです。

それから実際には「定義の強弱」も問題になります。
例えば『Float型の数字』と**話し言葉の範囲で**伝えても怒鳴る人は、そうそういないでしょう。数字や数値が曖昧なのに対して、Float型が扱えるものは、ちゃんと定義されているからです。
この場合、Float型がFloat型として処理する話である分には、全く問題ありません。別の型が影響してくると問題となる事例が発生するかもしれませんが。

ドキュメントには、まず真っ先に、この部分の定義を書け。と指導された経験があります。
型やクラスの概念が通用するのであれば「○○型で処理できるもの」とか「標準変換関数で対応する。対応できないものについては、都度説明する」みたいな記述も見たことがあります。

私からは、こんな回答です。

Answer (score 0):

「数字の1」はソースコード中の1という文字をイメージします
1でも"1"でも/1/でも数字の1が含まれています